# What are the Firestore data received?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, protocols

I'm trying to understand how Firestore (Firebase) works by reading the network packets, and I notice that I have a lot of similar results from requests that take less than 20ms on average (pretty fast!)

The data they contain are always the same format :

```
int
array[int, int, int]
```

For instance :

```
8
[1, 4, 7]
```

I tried to search on the Internet what was this used for, and how can it be interpreted, but couldn't find anything.

Is there a specification within the Firebase protocol that explains this?

### Update

Continuing in my quest, I noticed a request that takes 1 minute on average to complete. Analyzing that request shows that it receives data in a way that can be read by parts, not as a whole (contrary to a full JSON response).

Those 20ms requests are simply some data requests sent to Firestore, and the result is not pushed there, but on that "long-polling" request of 1 minute that will receive the new data that can be immediately used since they are structured in that specific way.

Comment: Firebase has 18+ products. Which one are you asking about? It would also help if you can show what API on that product you call to get those responses.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It would also help if you can show what API on that product you call to get those responses.

Comment: Try to find a proto definition on the firestore RPC API that matches that format.